# Trying to replace a specific character in a String with a new character

Tags: java, string

I am attempting to write a loop that will take a particular string and prompt the user to ask which character they would like to replace and which instance of this character(1st, 2nd, etc...) and I cannot figure out which method to have the program locate a desired character and replace it with a character of the user's choosing. This is what I currently have:

```
if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("replace single"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter the character to replace");
                    String rChar = keyboard.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Enter the new character");
                    String replacedChar = keyboard.nextLine();  
                    String rOneOutput = "";
                        for(int i=0; i< iLength; i++)
                        {   
                            
                            if (rChar.length() > 1)
                            {
                                System.out.println("Error you can only enter one character");
                            }
                            
                            else if(Input.substring(i, i+1).equals(rChar))
                            {
                                
                                
                                System.out.println("Which " + rChar + " would you like to replace?");
                                int index = keyboard.nextInt();
                                
                                if(Input.charAt(i)==rChar.charAt(0))
                                {
                                    rChar=Input;
                                }
                            
                                rOneOutput = (Input.substring(0)) + 
                                        replacedChar + Input.substring(index+1);
                                
                                System.out.println(rOneOutput); 
                                
                                
                            }
                            
                        }
```

Thanks for the help!
EDIT: (I can only use the string methods (charAt, substring, equals and length) so no indexOf unfortunately.

Comment: I don't see where `iLength` is defined.

Comment: Sorry about that I didn't realize I didn't have that in there.

Comment: iLength= Input.Length();

Comment: Input is what the string the user originally enters.

Comment: `substring(i, i+1)` If you are looking at one character, why create new substrings: Just use `if ( input.charAt(0) == c)` where c is rChar.charAt(0).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't use replace() a for loop is probably your best bet...

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    if (input.charAt(i) == charToReplace)
        input = input.substring(0,input.indexof(charToReplace))+newChar+input.substring(input.indexof(charToReplace) + 1)
```

updated solution

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    if (input.charAt(i) == charToReplace) {
        count++;
        if (count == 2)
             input = input.substring(0,input.indexof(charToReplace))+newChar+input.substring(input.indexof(charToReplace) + 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: In the instance where the user wants to replace the 3rd 'a' in 'a' string like "abbabbabba" how would I get it to locate the 3rd 'a' and replace it?

Comment: just updated with a solution that keeps count

Answer (score 0):

Not what you asked but the same idea.

```
String text = "hello";
char c = 'l';
char rc = '@';

int skip = 1;

int index = -1;
while (skip >= 0) {
    index += 1;
    if (text.charAt(index) == c) {
        skip -= 1;
    }
}

String newtext = text.substring(0, index) + rc + text.substring(index + 1);
```

This will output `hel@o`

Comment: Shoot I should've mentioned I can only use 4 of the string methods (charAt, substring, equals and length.) Sorry I'm new to this site I need to be more thorough.

Comment: Removed the indexOf